# How to handle redirect after login in ABP framework with Angular UI?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, abp, openiddict

I'm working with the ABP framework and Angular UI and facing a redirect problem.

Currently, I'm using **OpenIddict** for authentication purposes.

To reproduce my issue, follow these steps:

1. Log out of our app.
2. Try to access the app from a specific URL, in my case:
   http://localhost:4200/test;testId=1b285f09-2fd5-21ea-a956-3a0b46cb6b51
3. This will display a pop-up indicating that I need to be logged in to
   access. When I click "close" on the pop-up, it redirects me to the
   login page (which is correct).

[image]
4. It redirects to: https://localhost:44331/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%3Fresponse_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3DMyApp_App%26state%3DYn5BV29oVWRBZn44T1dYYU9FMnJTdXRBRFFVd1BVTUcyT2stWXhkSk5LX3R6%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A4200%26scope%3Dopenid%2520offline_access%MyApp%26code_challenge%3DDBlLQkXoYIzERyxcakvMiaSceZcGoj1w4j6bpyQN2jM%26code_challenge_method%3DS256%26nonce%3DYn5BV29oVWRBZn44T1dYYU9FMnJTdXRBRFFVd1BVTUcyT2stWXhkSk5LX3R6%26culture%3Den%26ui-culture%3Den

5. After logging in, I want to be redirected to the initially chosen
   URL:
   http://localhost:4200/test;testId=1b285f09-2fd5-21ea-a956-3a0b46cb6b51 but it is redirect me to the home page (http://localhost:4200/?iss=https:%2F%2Flocalhost:44331%2F)

How can I achieve this with Angular UI? I've seen a related [question](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/8045), but it doesn't provide the exact guidance I need. I hope someone can assist me with a complete example of how to accomplish this. Regards.